# is there any way to know which query is causing "no data found" exception?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any way to know which query is causing "no data found" exception in a big pl/sql block?  I have a big pl/sql block with many select into statements and an exception block. When i run that Stored procedure, I am getting No data found exception. i would like to know is there a way to print sql query which caused this exception using likes of sqlcode and sqlerrm?

Comment: The line number should be included in the `SQLERRM` message. Show us your code, the you will get help.

Comment: refer this link to use format_error_backtrace to find exact line where its failing http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_adv_plsql_format_error_backtrace.htm

Comment: Is your exception block catching `others` and then just printing `sqlerrm`? If so, don't do that; don't catch exceptions you don't need to handle, just let the exception propogate and the caller (e.g. client) see the full error stack. You'd then see exactly where the error was coming from.

Comment: Thank you All, All your inputs helped. dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace gave me line no details.